# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError) after dismissing the alert

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium-webdriver, capybara, modal-dialog

We have a Cucumber scenario that looks like this:

```
  @selenium
  Scenario: I can be told that geolocation is unavailable                                            # features/home_page.feature:57
    Given I am a visitor                                                                             # features/step_definitions/authentication_steps.rb:5
    When I visit the homepage                                                                        # features/step_definitions/home_page_steps.rb:1
    And I have declined geolocation permissions                                                      # features/step_definitions/home_page_steps.rb:14
    And I click the geolocate button                                                                 # features/step_definitions/home_page_steps.rb:18
    Then I see an alert "Unable to determine your current location. Please type an address instead." # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:104
```

The step `I see an alert "(.+?)"` is defined as:

```
Then(/^I see an alert "(.+?)"$/) do |content|
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.text.should == content
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.dismiss
end
```

For some reason, dismissing this alert doesn't suffice. The next scenario in line always fails with:

```
 Modal dialog present (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError)
 [remote server] file:///var/folders/x6/4vcz8vmj5ls2dbc9b3x2qxvh0000gp/T/webdriver-profile20130927-61014-emm2oz/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10521:in `nsCommandProcessor.execute'
 [remote server] file:///var/folders/x6/4vcz8vmj5ls2dbc9b3x2qxvh0000gp/T/webdriver-profile20130927-61014-emm2oz/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:7510:in `Dispatcher.executeAs/<'
 [remote server] file:///var/folders/x6/4vcz8vmj5ls2dbc9b3x2qxvh0000gp/T/webdriver-profile20130927-61014-emm2oz/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:7668:in `Resource.handle'
 [remote server] file:///var/folders/x6/4vcz8vmj5ls2dbc9b3x2qxvh0000gp/T/webdriver-profile20130927-61014-emm2oz/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:7615:in `Dispatcher.dispatch'
 [remote server] file:///var/folders/x6/4vcz8vmj5ls2dbc9b3x2qxvh0000gp/T/webdriver-profile20130927-61014-emm2oz/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:10336:in `WebDriverServer/<.handle'
 [remote server] file:///var/folders/x6/4vcz8vmj5ls2dbc9b3x2qxvh0000gp/T/webdriver-profile20130927-61014-emm2oz/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1935:in `unknown'
 [remote server] file:///var/folders/x6/4vcz8vmj5ls2dbc9b3x2qxvh0000gp/T/webdriver-profile20130927-61014-emm2oz/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:2261:in `ServerHandler.handleResponse'
 [remote server] file:///var/folders/x6/4vcz8vmj5ls2dbc9b3x2qxvh0000gp/T/webdriver-profile20130927-61014-emm2oz/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1168:in `Connection.process'
 [remote server] file:///var/folders/x6/4vcz8vmj5ls2dbc9b3x2qxvh0000gp/T/webdriver-profile20130927-61014-emm2oz/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1616:in `RequestReader._handleResponse'
 [remote server] file:///var/folders/x6/4vcz8vmj5ls2dbc9b3x2qxvh0000gp/T/webdriver-profile20130927-61014-emm2oz/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1464:in `RequestReader._processBody'
 [remote server] file:///var/folders/x6/4vcz8vmj5ls2dbc9b3x2qxvh0000gp/T/webdriver-profile20130927-61014-emm2oz/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1333:in `RequestReader.onInputStreamReady'
 /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:51:in `assert_ok'
 /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
 /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
 /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
 /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
 /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
 /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:629:in `raw_execute'
 /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:607:in `execute'
 /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:356:in `deleteAllCookies'
 /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/options.rb:67:in `delete_all_cookies'
 /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/capybara-2.0.3/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:67:in `reset!'
 /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/capybara-2.0.3/lib/capybara/session.rb:75:in `reset!'
 /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/capybara-2.0.3/lib/capybara.rb:253:in `block in reset_sessions!'
 /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/capybara-2.0.3/lib/capybara.rb:253:in `each'
 /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/capybara-2.0.3/lib/capybara.rb:253:in `reset_sessions!'
 /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@geostellar/gems/capybara-2.0.3/lib/capybara/cucumber.rb:10:in `Before'
```

We've tried upgrading selenium-webdriver and capybara to no avail. The only thing that has worked so far is to duplicate the dismiss line, which feels gross but always gets rid of the dialog. There's definitely only one dialog, so what gives?

Comment: which line giving this error..Could you give the link on to which you ran your code...?

Comment: Do you use turbolinks? Or there may be a hint with AJAX. http://makandracards.com/makandra/10881-understanding-the-selenium-error-modal-dialog-present

Comment: Not using turbolinks or any AJAX here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try using `.accept` instead of `.dismiss`. I've had better luck using `.accept` on these pop ups then `.dismiss`.  So the full line that you'll want to try is

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
```